# How to check if trusted origins are already exist in okta via terraform

Tags: terraform, okta, terraform-provider

I wanted to create a trusted origin in okta via terraform by using "okta_trusted_origin" form a list of urls.
I would like to know how can I check if the URL is already exist in okta trusted origins, don't create a new one.

I tried using a filter in "okta_trusted_origins" data source, but I'm not sure what would be the correct search criteria

Here is my code:

```
resource "okta_trusted_origin" "trusted_origin" {
  count = length(data.okta_trusted_origins.all.trusted_origins) == 0 ? 1 : 0

  name   = var.name
  origin = var.origin
  scopes = var.scopes
}

data "okta_trusted_origins" "all" {
  filter = "trusted_origins.origin eq ${var.origin}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct filter syntax is:

```
data "okta_trusted_origins" "all" {
  filter = "origin eq \"${var.origin}\""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is a "desired state" system, and so a declaration like "this object should exist if it doesn't exist" is a contradiction: the object can't both exist and not exist at the same time.

If you were to succeed in telling Terraform that rule then you would create a configuration that cannot converge: the first run would detect that the object doesn't exist and propose to create it, and then the second run would detect that the object exists and propose to destroy it.

Instead, you must explicitly tell Terraform whether each object should exist or not. It's your responsibility as the author of your configurations to decide which system is responsible for managing each object, and (when any of those systems are Terraform-based) declare the object only in the configuration that ought to be managing it.

Terraform expects that you will tell it whether the object should already exist (using a `data` block) *or* whether Terraform should ensure that it exists (using a `resource` block). There is no way to make that decision automatically because then it would be ambiguous which configuration is the one responsible for updating and destroying the object in future.

Comment: We can use "okta_trusted_origins" data source. I was just not sure what would be the valid filter syntax.

Comment: How does your configuration behave when you run `terraform apply` a second time after the `okta_trusted_origin.trusted_origin` object has been created? I expect that Terraform will propose to destroy the object, as I described in my answer.

Comment: I'm checking if it exist via okta_trusted_origins filter to avoid creating it again

Comment: The problem is not to avoid creating it again, but rather to avoid destroying it once Terraform notices it already exists, because your configuration says "this should only exist if it doesn't exist".

Comment: That's right! I don't need the filter